# Javascript not working when page loads relatively

Tags: 2013, 2016

I have a content editor webpart which references a HTML file

It has the below code

SCRIPT

```
<script>

function changeimageurl(imagepath){
    document.getElementById("slidecontainer").src=imagepath;
};

</script>
```

`
    **HTML**

```
<li onclick='changeimageurl("../gallery/_w/Slide1_JPG.jpg")' > "SOME LINK"</li>
```

This works fine when I directly go to page with url like

```
http://sitelink.com/sites/SUBSITE/webpages/gallery.aspx
```

But when I click on the quick launch on left side, it is loading page as

```
http://sitelink.com/sites/subsite/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/webpages/gallery.aspx
```

When the page loads like this, the changeimageurl function is undefined and the onclick is not working

Can I make the quick launch load the direct page instead of relative page with `#/webpages` ?

Or is there a work around?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> You are noticing the URL with _layouts/15/start.aspx because the new
>   feature Minimal Download Strategy is activated on your site.
>
> To know more on how it works you can refer the below links
>
> [Introduction to
>   MDS](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013---introduction-to-the-minimal-download-strategy-mds)
>
> [What is start.aspx in SP
>   2013](http://www.hezser.de/blog/archive/2012/08/18/what-is-the-_layouts15start-aspx-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)
>
> If you don't want _layouts/15/start.aspx to be a part of your URL you
>   need to deactivate Minimal Download Strategy feature available under
>   Site Actions -> Manage Site Features
>
> Note: Minimal Download Strategy is a new framework which is been
>   written to increase the performance of the SharePoint site.

Source: [Removing _layouts/15/start.aspx# from the URL on the address bar](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b0c0d054-a54d-46fe-a2f1-65fbd88e2a03/removing-layouts15startaspx-from-the-url-on-the-address-bar?forum=sharepointadmin)

**UPDATE**

As per comments from @wjervis, as an alternative to not disabling MDS functionality you can use `RegisterModuleInit()` method.

Ref: [Register CSR Override on MDS enabled SP2013 site](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sridhara/2013/02/08/register-csr-override-on-mds-enabled-sharepoint-2013-site/)

Comment: Here's a link that mentions `RegisterModuleInit()`, the function that registers your scripts to work with MDS, if you want to add an alternative to just disabling MDS to your answer: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sridhara/2013/02/08/register-csr-override-on-mds-enabled-sharepoint-2013-site/

Answer (score 7):

You can disable the Minimal download strategy feature for the site, located under site settings > Manage site features.

That's what adding the extra string to your URL. ("/_layouts/15/start.aspx#").